# remain iPhones's camera open in background in lockscreen

Tags: iphone, swift, ios11, xcode9

i need a minute here, I want to that in swift what should I do if I want to record videos using iPhone's camera in background in lock screen. I am not very much familiar with iOS programming, so kindly explain it at beginners level, any help would be hugely counted and appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't let the camera open when leaving foreground, and especially not when the device is locked. Basically you can't.

Comment: can we off the display while recording, like in the app just the screen goes black.

Comment: You might be able to do something like that but I don't think Apple will allow it if you don't give them a really good reason. If it's for the purpose of spying you probably can abort the idea.